# Catch-all rescue

Tags: ruby, rescue

In Ruby/Rails, is there a "catch-all" `rescue` statement that also allows for more specific `rescue` possibilities? I tried

```
begin
  # something
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  # do something
rescue SocketError
  # do something else
rescue 
  # do yet another thing
end
```

It turns out that even when there's `URI::InvalidURIError` or `SocketError`, it goes into the last `rescue` (i.e. it executes `do yet another thing`.) I want it to `do something`, or `do something else`, respectively.

Comment: First, I doubt that when a `URI::InvalidURIError` or `SocketError` is raised it goes into the last `rescue`—that's just not how Ruby works. Second, you want something that gets everything else, but is specific? Not sure if that even makes semantic sense, as a catch-all is, by definition, non-specific.

Comment: I think maybe he meant that he needs a solution for more specific rescues because he believes the correct way doesn't work.  Perhaps what's really happening is that a different error is being thrown in the block before the errors you expect.  You should probably inspect the error that you're actually catching in that last rescue to see what's happening.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Thanks for your suggestion. How could I inspect the error I'm catching in the last rescue?

Comment: `Rails.logger.error(!$)` or change the rescue to `rescue => e`, then `Rails.logger.error(e)`.  It'll show up in your log.  Or, go ahead and reraise it so it's not caught at all by `raise $!` in the block.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall and numbers1311407 You're all correct. I misunderstood something. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
require 'socket'

Errors = [URI::InvalidURIError, SocketError]
a = lambda { |e=nil|
             begin
               raise e unless e.nil? 
             rescue URI::InvalidURIError
               puts "alligator"
             rescue SocketError
               puts "crocodile"
             rescue
               puts "vulture"
             else
               puts "rhino"
             end }
```

Now try

```
a.( Errors[ 0 ] )
a.( Errors[ 1 ] )
a.call
```

It will behave exactly as you need. If your code above doesn't work, then something else is going on in your program than you think.